# Find the first id of any descendant using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For draggable divs in JS on my page, I want to store the last location in local storage so that when a user refreshes, the draggable elements on the page stay put.

My HTML is in general like this:

```
<div id="some_id" class="draggable">
    <p>I am a draggable thing.</p>
</div>
```

I then use the `id` of the `div` as a key in local storage so that having multiple draggable objects on the page doesn't result in them all being given the same position on refresh.

However, templates like this are sometimes used inside a template which handles visibility, so sometimes they'll be like this:

```
<div class="visibility_container draggable">
    <button class="close_button">Close</button>
    <div id="some_id">
        <p>I am a draggable thing.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `draggable` class is added programmatically each time.

These templates may vary but will never have `id`s within them – they'd be pretty terrible templates if they did – so I only need to find the first descendant element which has an `id` and use the value of that `id` as my local storage key.

How can I find the nearest element with JS? I'm aware that jQuery has a `.closest()` method which finds the nearest ancestor – I need to go in the opposite direction. I'm also aware of jQuery's `.find()` which can find me all descendants matching a selector, but I'm unsure I can guarantee the order in which jQuery returns these children as [the API docs](https://api.jquery.com/find/) were not clear on that point.

Comment: Does `.find()` not do the trick?

Comment: *"These templates may vary but will never have ids within them – they'd be pretty terrible templates if they did – so I only need to find the first descendant element which has an id and use the value of that id as my local storage key."* If they don't have `id`s in them, how can you find the first element inside them that has an `id`?

Comment: The templates themselves have parts which can be replaced – I'm using a pretty heinous string replacement, so the template has a `%content%` string somewhere for example, and that is replaced by the `div#some_id` on page creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm also aware of jQuery's .find() which can find me all descendants matching a selector, but I'm unsure I can guarantee the order in which jQuery returns these children as the API docs were not clear on that point.

`find` lists elements in *document order* (aka "DOM order") (and you're right, I'm surprised not to see a clear statement of that in the docs). "Document order" is a well-defined DOM term, it means a depth-first search of the descendant elements. Or put it another way: The one whose text is first in the markup.

So for instance:

```
<div id="container">
   <div>
      <div>
          <div id="one"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

...then

```
console.log($("#container").find("[id]").first().attr("id"));
```

...will log `one`, not `two`.

This document order thing is common across most of the jQuery API and DOM methods like `querySelectorAll`, `getElementsByTagName`, and such. I'm not having any luck finding a clear statement of it in the jQuery documentation, though, which seems like an oversight. The closest I've found so far is a bit documenting an *exception* to that (e.g., saying [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) that *"The second and third...create a jQuery object using one or more DOM elements that were already selected in some other way...**unlike** most other multi-element jQuery operations, the elements are not sorted in DOM order."* [my emphasis].) The [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) docs also point out that the results will be in document order (not the order of the selectors).